# Implementing Remember Me in Padrino 0.11 with new admin interface

Tags: ruby, authentication, cookies, sinatra, padrino

I'm trying to implement a 'Remember Me' feature in the new Padrino 0.11 Admin interface, but having a little bit of trouble due to the differences between it and Rails. Basically, I'm following along with http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password.

I've managed to get the Remember Me and auth_token working handily, and I can see the cookie in the Dev console when I go to look at it. I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get the application to do autologin *on* the cookie when it is present though. I'm sure it's something stupid, but this is where I'm up to.

For instance, I've got the actual Remember Me creating an auth_token and setting it fine to the cookie (I can see it on localhost) in the dev console on Chrome via this in the sessions controller.

*admin/controllers/sessions*

```
post :create do
  if account = Account.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    set_current_account(account)
    if params[:remember_me]
      response.set_cookie('da_app', value: account.auth_token,
                              expires: (Time.now + 1.year + 1.day))
    end
    flash[:success] = "You've successfully logged in as #{account.name}."
    redirect url(:base, :index)
  else
    params[:email], params[:password] = h(params[:email]), h(params[:password])
    flash[:error] = pat('login.error')
    redirect url(:sessions, :new)
  end
end
```

However, due to my inexperience with padrino, a little stumped as to where I'd put the bit of logic which triggers before an incoming request, checks for the cookie and then logs the user in. I tried the following, which is not perfect but which is definitely not working (though not sure why... =< ) and in fact, the code block to detect the cookie does not even seem to be firing (which seems pretty basic.).

*admin/app.rb (not sure this is the right place for it actually)*

```
before '/*' do
  if request.cookies['da_app'].exists?
    set_current_account(Account.find_by_auth_token(request.cookies['da_app']))
    redirect url(:base, :index)
  end
end
```

So, I'm sure it's probably dead simple to solve but a bit stumped on this one (and also, am really trying to avoid using a gem plugin like padrino-warden or the like at the moment and implement this from scratch as an exercise.).

*(Also, bonus karma points on helping solve this one as I'm implementing this as part of some pro bono work for a global conservation charity.)*